# Ubuntu 18.10 boots to emergency mode then to tty1

Tags: boot, tty

I recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows 10. I had a semi-fresh install, I had Ubuntu 18.10 with a minimal install. I of course downloaded some apps and everything was working great. Then I remembered I had a couple important files on my windows install. So I powered my machine off, then plugged my windows SSD into a sata port and turned it back on. However instead of the normal Ubuntu splash/loading screen, it is plain text that says "Ubuntu Budgie 18.10". Then it boots into emergency mode. I press ctrl-d to continue, and it puts me into a tty login screen. GNOME isn't gone, I can still boot into it, by using this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

However internet doesn't work, so I have to manually restart the network-manager service in terminal, and who knows how many other services are broken. Having to manually open everything isn't a big deal to me, it's just mildly annoying. I'm just concerned because it means there are probably other errors that will come down the road from this, and I would like to fix this as soon as I can.

Please keep in mind, I'm nearly a complete noob to the linux terminal. All I know are apt-get commands, what sudo does, and basic navigation of file systems.

(If it matters) Specs:
CPU: AMD A10-5800K
GPU: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (With proprietary drivers)
RAM: 16GB (800MHz DDR3)

Comment: Please don't add solution to your question itself, solutions should always be posted as an answer. I've removed the solution from the question, but you should be able to find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1104121/2). Please post it as an answer below by clicking the 'Answer your question' button. Also don't add 'Solved' to the title. The correct way to do it here is by "accepting" the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue has been solved, my Fstab file, for whatever reason, was completely empty. I replaced it with a backup and everything works fine now.
>   <sub>(originally [added to the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1104121/2) by OP)</sub>